# NSView's context NSMenu is never shown even though all the right methods are being called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nsmenu, nscollectionview

I have an `NSCollectionView` with a bunch of `NSView`s in it, stacked vertically, to make it look a bit like `UIKit`'s `UITableView`. Everything works as expected, except for one thing:

When right-clicking any one of the `NSView`s, I expect the `NSMenu` I set to be view's `menu` to be shown, but alas - nothing happens.

The crazy part is all the right methods are being called, exactly as could be expected: `-rightMouseDown:`, `-menuForEvent:` and finally `-menu`.

When I set up any object as the `NSMenu`'s `delegate`, `menuWillOpen:` is **not** called, so it seems to me something fails over on Apple's side of things, just in between asking for the `menu`, and actually showing it.

Would anyone be able to shed a light on this?

Thanks in advance.

PS. For what it's worth, `NSMenu`s I present manually (without relying on Apple's right-click handling) using `popUpMenuPositioningItem:atLocation:inView:` *are* shown.

## Edit / Update / Clarification

The `NSCollectionView` in question is inside an `NSWindow` that's being shown when an `NSStatusItem` is clicked, like CoverSutra/TicToc/what have you. Some code from the `MyWindow` `NSWindow` subclass:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
    [self setExcludedFromWindowsMenu:YES];
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeMainWindow {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isMovable {
    return NO;
}

- (void)presentFromPoint:(NSPoint)point {
    point.y -= self.frame.size.height;
    point.x -= self.frame.size.width / 2;
    [self setFrameOrigin:point];
    [self makeMainWindow];
    [self makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

`presentFromPoint:` is the method I use to present it from any point I like, in my case from just below the `NSStatusItem`. (Not really relevant to this problem)

My application has `LSUIElement` in its `Info.plist` set to `YES` by the way, so it doesn't show a menu bar or a Dock icon. It lives in the status bar, and has a window that's shown when the `NSStatusItem` is clicked.

The view hierarchy is as follows:

`MyWindow` => `contentView` => `NSScrollView` => `NSCollectionView`

The `NSCollectionView` has an `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass connected to its `itemPrototype` property, and the `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass has an `NSView` subclass connected to its `view` property.
The `NSView` subclass, in turn, has an `NSMenu` connected to its `menu` property.
And last but not least: This `NSMenu` has one `NSMenuItem` sitting inside it.

Both the `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass and the `NSView` subclass do nothing interesting as of now, they're just empty subclasses.

The `NSMenu` connected to the `NSView`'s `menu` property is what should be shown when the `NSView` is right-clicked, but as I hope I have made clear: It isn't actually shown.

## Update

I still have no idea what caused this problem, but I've decided to 'move on' from `NSCollectionView`, as it wasn't really fit for what I was trying to do anyway, and I am now using [`TDListView`](https://github.com/amazingsyco/TDAppKit) which works like a charm.